# Should I use express-generator npm package?

Tags: node.js, express, npm

In [express official getting started](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html), They suggest using `express-generator`..

When I tried to install it using `npm`, it gave me about 50 vulnerabilities, among which there are 10 critical ones

So, what should I do? Skip those vulnerability messages or use other package? And if use other package, which one do you recommend?

And what should I do in general when I get those vulnerability messages? As I got some on installing `npx`